# Creating multiple MySQL inserts from a single click (inventory system)

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm building an inventory system. Basically, the user would type in a received quantity and the system will generate an individual stock number for each unit. So far I have 2 tables created. One for the main stock info and a second one for individual stock items related to the main stock info. I am having a problem figuring out how to create the individual items depending on the quantity the user enterred in a textbox. I can insert the data for the main stock info but how can I create the entries for the individual items? This is the code to enter the main stock info. I could sure use some help here. Thanks.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // generate stock number button pressed
        ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"];
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString());
        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(@"insert into shopmanager.inventory (projects_project_number, inv_name, inv_description, inv_quantity, inv_date_received) values(@projects_project_number, @inv_name, @inv_description, @inv_quantity, @inv_date_received)", con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projects_project_number", project.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inv_name", item_name.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inv_description", item_description.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inv_quantity", quantity_received.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inv_date_received", DateTime.Now);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd1.Parameters.Clear();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to generate stock numbers or how to run <quantity> number of inserts?

Comment: how to run <quantity> number of inserts. The stock numbers are auto-increment.

Comment: so you wanna add every 1 qty as 1 record ?

Comment: This is exact. Every item needs an individual stock number

Comment: even if its same item ?

Comment: yes. All items are serialized so they need to be individual items

Comment: hmm so depending on insert you can run a "for loop" and return qty as 1 for every insert

Comment: yes. That is what I will be using but the question is how do I create the mutiple entries depending on the quantity entered by the user

Comment: @Halilİbrahim would you have a code example by any chance. I'm new to coding so i'm unsure how to do this

Comment: Is there any table store All items or How could you get  All items?

Comment: if you are letting user enter Quantity from a text box then get the value from text box and i=0;i<valueYouHadFromUser;i++; ? and in insert values send Qty as 1 for each insert into command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html:

Simply set the parameters again for each record.

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd;

conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();

conn.ConnectionString = strConnection;

try
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(NULL, @number, @text)";
    cmd.Prepare();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", 1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", "One");

    for (int i=1; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@number"].Value = i;
        cmd.Parameters["@text"].Value = "A string value";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Number + " has occurred: " + ex.Message,
        "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

That's how you would technically do it.  However, I question why you would let someone enter a quantity, and then proceed to enter a record where your quantity in essence would always be 1. Normally, you would just use the quantity to indicate how many items are on hand unless the items are pretty much unique/custom made. i.e. you're slapping a barcode on the item and scanning it to know what specific piece of supply you are using.

Otherwise, you would just slap a barcode that says it's Part #XYZ, and it doesn't matter which piece you get because it's Part #XYZ.

Other cases to have multiple inventory line items are rolling stock or getting the same parts from different suppliers/manufacturers (and that has more to do with tracking costs and potentially QC)

Comment: There are some items that are not serialized but alot of them are (same part but needs to have an individual serial number). My problem was the serialized ones (QC requirement)

Comment: @ChristianVerner makes sense.